# Is there a way to allow Chrome notifications when using any other app in fullscreen?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I recently started using Notifications in Chrome and noticed that they aren't showing when I'm using any other app in fullscreen, for example playing video with mpv or playing games. I'd like to them to show whenever though, so I can quickly know whats happening.

I'm on Windows 10, tried disabling focus assist and fullscreen optimizations didn't help, as long as I have an app in fullscreen they just don't show up.

I did tests with [this](https://www.bennish.net/web-notifications.html) website.

Authorize, and press show in 5s, then quickly switch to mpv with fullscreen wait 10 sec. and notification didn't show up, yet it shows up immediately after I exit fullscreen.

Is there a way to force notifications to show regardless of what I have in fullscreen?

I tested the same in Firefox, it works the same way but except the last part the notification doesn't show up at all after I exit fullscreen mpv.

Comment: Please show how exactly  you configured focus assist. And even more importantly mention the app that doesn't work, if a recommended solution doesn't work for it, you should ofc be way more specific instead of just calling it an "app".

Comment: @Destroy666 Focus assist set to Disabled, all other switches below as well. App is any fullscreen app, as I said in question: MPV player or any game.

Comment: Sorry, missed mpv, but the "other app" part before it wasn't clear, I corrected it to say "any other app".

Comment: Try `sfc`/`dism` fixes or upgrading to latest Windows 10 if you haven't. For me it works to just turn off fullscreen app setting in focus assist.

Comment: @Destroy666 I don't know why, but it just doesn't work for me... With latest Windows 10 and completely disabled Focus Assist...